# Powershell RunAs Administrator

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have the script bellow which I would like to have run itself as Administrator without using a batch file.

The issue is that when I run the script, it opens a new administrator window and then just closes immediately.

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))

{   
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
Break
}

Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName | Select-Object -Property DisplayName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-NoExit` to the PowerShell command line (otherwise, when given a script, it exits when that script has completed).

Comment: Where exactly?  I have tried in many places on all lines but it still exits or throws the parameter cannot be found error.

Answer (score -1):

Add the `-noexit` to the argumentlist that launches your elevated process.

Comment: Such as the answer above?